# Proving $g(|a_n|^2) = \ln(1+|a_n|^2)$ for the conserved quantity

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align*}i\frac{d}{dt}a_{n}(t) &= (a_{n+1}(t) + a_{n-1}(t))(1+|a_{n}(t)|^2), \;n \in \mathbb{Z}\end{align*}
Consider the conserved quantity $$P = \sum\limits_{n}g(|a_n|^2)$$
What is the function $g(|a_n|^2)$ which makes $P$ conserved, i.e., $\frac{d}{dt}P = 0$ for all $\{a_{n}(t)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$?

---

I am a bit loose in my proof attempt below in writing $f(\xi)$ in that I do not say how large of an annulus $\xi_{ref}$ needs to be. Same with the linear independence. Is there a better way to approach this?

---

\begin{align}0 &= \frac{d}{dt} \sum\limits_{n} g(|a_n|^2) \\
&= \sum\limits_{n}\frac{dg(|a_n|^2)}{dt} \frac{d(a_n a_n^{*})}{dt}\\
&= \sum\limits_{n}g'(|a_n|^2)\Big(\frac{d}{dt}[a_{n}] a_{n}^{*} + a_{n}\frac{d}{dt}[a_{n}^{*}]\Big)\\
&= \sum\limits_{n}g'(|a_{n}|^2)(1+|a_n|^2)(-i(a_{n+1} + a_{n-1})a_{n}^{*} + a_{n}i(a_{n+1}^{*} + a_{n-1}^{*})\\
&= -i\sum\limits_{n}g'(|a_{n}|^2)(1+|a_n|^2)\Big ((a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*} -a_{n}a_{n-1}^{*}) -(a_{n+1}^{*}a_{n} - a_{n}^{*}a_{n-1})\Big)\\
\end{align}
Immediately one may identify that if $g' = \frac{1}{1+|a_n|^2}$ then what remains is a vanishing telescoping sum. However, since I desire Mathematica to do most of the work eventually, then let us continue as I am unsure if Mathematica can arrive at this deduction. Recall $z - z^{*} = 2i\mathfrak{Im}[z]$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
\begin{align}
&=  2\sum\limits_{n}g'(|a_{n}|^2)(1+|a_n|^2)\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*} - a_{n}a_{n-1}^{*}\Big]\\
\end{align}
Let $z_n = g'(|a_n|^2)(1+|a_n|^2)$ and let $x_{n} := \mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]$.
\begin{align}
0&= \sum\limits_{n}z_n(x_n - x_{n-1})\\
&= \sum\limits_{n}(z_{n} - z_{n+1})x_{n}\\
&= \sum\limits_{n}( g'(|a_n|^2)(1+|a_n|^2) -  g'(|a_{n+1}|^2)(1+|a_{n+1}|^2))\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]
\end{align}
Let $f(\xi) = g'(\xi)(1+\xi)$.
\begin{align}
0&=\sum\limits_{n}(f(|a_n|^2 - f(|a_{n+1}|^2)))\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]
\end{align}
Consider the Laurent series of $f$ about $\xi_{ref}$ with constants $\alpha_p$. Applying this form of $f$ we have

\begin{align}
0&= \sum\limits_{n}\sum\limits_{p}\alpha_{p} \Big ( (|a_n|^2 - \xi_{ref})^p - (|a_{n+1}|^2 - \xi_{ref})\Big )\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]\\
&=\sum_{p}\alpha_{p}\sum_{n}\Big ( (|a_n|^2 - \xi_{ref})^p - (|a_{n+1}|^2 - \xi_{ref})^{p}\Big )\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]
\end{align}

Each $p$-summand is independently zero because of linear independence.

\begin{align}
0 &= \alpha_{p}\sum\limits_{n}\Big ( (|a_n|^2 - \xi_{ref})^p - (|a_{n+1}|^2 - \xi_{ref})^{p}\Big )\mathfrak{Im}\Big[a_{n+1}a_{n}^{*}\Big]
\end{align}

This reduces to two cases:

$p=0 \implies \alpha_0$ is free.

$p\neq 0 \implies \alpha_p = 0$ since the sum in $n$ is not necessarily zero.

Therefore $f(\xi) = \alpha_0$ is a constant. Therefore $g'(\xi) = \frac{a_0}{1 + \xi}$. This leaves $g(\xi) = \alpha_0 \ln(1+\xi) + c$ where $\alpha_0$ and $c$ are unconstrained.